# Вывести строку, удовлетворяющую условию

Tags: python

Подскажите с вопросом.
Есть строка и список, в котором хранятся символы (символы могут быть частью слова, а могут быть вообще рандомными). Нужно вывести максимальную строку (элемент списка), которая является частью слова.

Напрмиер:

```
line = 'привет'
list_with_letters = ['п', 'qwe', 'пр', 'hello', 'прив', 'прйцу']

Вывод:
прив
```

Скажите, можно ли это сделать с помощью max и key?
Например:

```
for word in list_with_letters:
    if ... max(word, key=len)?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ответ в одну строку:

```
max([word for word in list_with_letters if word in line], key=len)
```

Ещё как вариант можно воспользоваться функцией `filter`:

```
max(filter(lambda w: w in line, list_with_letters), key=len)
```